# What is the name of the substance that underwent the ductility test in the YouTube video Ductility Test?

Tags: materials

In the YouTube video [Ductility Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjBbfcK3Y8Y), I saw a black substance undergo a ductility test. It appeared to be as ductile as silly putty although silly putty is just a very viscous liquid. It seems that it can keep being pulled thinner and thinner. I couldn't find the name of the substance in the video. I just want to know the name of that substance. Once I learn the name of that substance, I can ask another question about the properties of that substance.

I'll ask whether it's a solid unlike silly putty. I know it started off as a liquid but I'll ask whether it got turned into a solid or just a very viscous liquid. I'll ask "If it's a solid, what is its yield strength?" If it has a higher yield strength than the typical chromium steel, it could be very revolutionary because it cannot sustain crack propagation and therefore cannot be weakened much by the presence of a crack.

Comment: I suggest including the youtube link in body of the questions.

Comment: It is Asphalt (bitumen) tested per ASTM D 113.

Comment: And the final frame of the test identifies it as bitumen.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare your video with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE8zYxUJHt0 which uses a very similar test procedure, the material is probably the same: bitumen.